# Is it possible to have a permanent token

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a web application and I want to give the ability for the user to connect his Outlook account with my web application.
Which will give the ability to create a meeting in his calendar once he adds it in the system.

I've create an Azure AD application, the user can login and generate an access token which I can create the meeting using Graph API.
and refresh token isn't working from backend service.

But my problem is that I need a permanent token so the user doesn't have to login again,
same as the outlook calendar app in slack.

Is there a specific configuration that I need to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: OAuth2.0 with `offline_access` scope iirc

Comment: Can you make sure that you are using `authorization code flow` with `offline_access` ? Also it would be really great if you can provide some sample code block